# any singleton pattern early instantiated issues

Tags: java, singleton, instantiation, java-memory-model

I came across some issues using lazy instantiated singleton pattern

Reference: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html.

Similarly is there any issues in using early instantiated singleton pattern?

Comment: Why are so many people interested in the Singleton pattern?

Comment: @duffymo: because there are so many blog posts and questions about it, so people get the impressions it is important

Answer (score 3):

This was written about ten years ago.  Since 2004, the simplest Singleton pattern is to use an `enum`, with one instance.

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea seems to be that instantiating the singleton may be costly, so if it's done early (and perhaps for a lot of singletons)  it may lead to a long pause when the application starts, whereas lazy instatiation spreads the delays around and may avoid them entirely if a singleton is not always needed.

Is this really an issue for a significant number of applications? I am very certain it is not, and the amount of blog posts and questions about lazily-instantiated singletons is completely out of proportion to its practical usefulness. I am equally certain all this attention has given a lot of people the impression that this is how Singletons must be implemented and caused them to choose an unnecessarily complex solution in places where a straightforward semi-eagerly instantiated Singleton would have been perfectly fine.

So why does this issue get so much attention? I suspect that it's partially the fact that it illustrates some finer points of the Java memory model that are relevant for concurrent code in general, and partially a game of smartassery.